# How make xamarin projects to open in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, xamarin, project

I have found that everytime I try to open a xamarin project (F#) in visual studio I get the error "Project not loaded". And the inverse too.

Is not possible to have a single project that open and work between the two?

Comment: It should open 1 or more project though I haven't used F# myself. I suspect you have a licensing issue with Xamarin or perhaps the SDK for your platform is not setup correctly from the Xamarin perspective.

Comment: Try reinstalling the tools?

Comment: I mean normal .net projects, not ios/android but your basic F# command line project.